# Microsoft WinForms Chart Control - TitleBox

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-chart-controls

I am looking to produce this type of TitleBox in the Microsoft WinForms Chart Control, so that the titlebox is docked to the top of the chartarea.

[image]

Is there any way to position the standard titlebox on the top of the chartarea like this or can I add such a textbox to the chart control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: You can add a `Label` into the `Chart` like this:

```
int lh = (int)(label1.Height / chart1.Height * 100f);
int cw = chart1.Width;

ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
ElementPosition EP = CA.InnerPlotPosition;
CA.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(EP.X, EP.Y + lh, EP.Width, EP.Height - lh);
label1.Location = new Point((int)(EP.X * cw / 100f) + 10, 0);
label1.Width = (int)(EP.Width * cw / 100f) - 20;
label1.Height -= 2;
label1.Parent = chart1;
```

Or you may want to position the Label by docking it to the top..

You can style the `Label` to your liking, even add an `Image`..

You may need to play with the offset for the label.Height!

[image]

Option 2: You can move the Title box around in the same way:

```
chart1.Titles.Add("TiltelBox");
Title T = chart1.Titles[0];
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

T.DockedToChartArea = CA.Name;
T.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
T.Docking = Docking.Top;
T.IsDockedInsideChartArea = true;
ElementPosition EP = T.Position;
T.Position = new ElementPosition
                (EP.X + 10f, EP.Y -0.5f, EP.Width + 83.5f, EP.Height + 9f);
```

[image]

Again: you will want to play around with the way you position the Title. The ones above happend to work here but you will need to change them with you chart..

Remember that the [ElementPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.elementposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses 1/100 of the chart size as its unit; this is nice as it scales but makes it hard to set up at first..